# error A2070: invalid instruction operands IN SSE MASM64

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, masm, sse

when compiling this in ml64.exe 64bit (masm64)
the SSE command give me an error
what do i need to do to include the SSE commands in 64 bit?

```
.code

foo PROC

  movlps [rdx], xmm7 ;;error A2070: invalid instruction operands
  movhlps xmm6, xmm7
  movss [rdx+8], xmm6 ;;rror A2070: invalid instruction operands
  ret

foo ENDP

end
```

i get the error:

```
1>Performing Custom Build Step
1> Assembling: extasm.asm
1>extasm.asm(6) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
1>extasm.asm(10) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
1>Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 8.00.50727.215
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Custom Build Step"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So modify the two lines to:

movlps QWORD PTR[rdx], xmm7

movss dword ptr [rdx+8], xmm6

like here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/4f473acb-7b14-4bf4-bed3-e5e87e1f81e7

Comment: You need to edit this, a bare link isn't very helpful. Does it or does it not answer the question?